# How many block of external memory does deleteMin access for a binary heap priority queue?

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue, computation-theory

I'm studying priority queues, which use binary heaps as their internal data structure. Considering the external memory model with block size M, the slides claim that deleteMin requires approximately `2log(n/M)` block accesses.

Why is this? I could not find an explanation in the original paper describing the bottom up heuristic (Wegener 93), nor in the slides.

The first block contains the root and the first log(M) levels of the heap. After that, for each node it must read one block per level, which will contain the two consecutive child nodes. Only in rare cases (hence the "approximate") will it have to read two block to fetch both children of a node. As the first log(M) levels will be read with a single block access, it will only have to load blocks for the lowest `(log n - log M) = log n/M` levels.

Where does the `2` come from? It will have to write the blocks back to disk on cache eviction, but isn't that usually accounted for with the load?

I hope I've explained the question well enough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis seems correct to me.  There is no need for the `2`.

By the way, usually external memory algorithms use `M` as the memory size and `B` as the block size.  so it would be `log(n/B)` block accesses (as long as `M>2B` or so).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm aware that usually `M` and `B` are used. All of the slides of this lecture do so as well, but this particular one makes use of `M` in the mentioned way. As to why, I have no idea. As `M` would be the size of the whole cache, one would assume, that the whole cache would be loaded with the beginning of the heap's array in one I/O time step. This doesn't make much sense to me however.